# C++ (Allegro Library) Bitmap Two-Dimensional Array Question

Tags: c++, allegro

I have a quick question. I am using C++ with the Allegro library.

If I make the following declaration `BITMAP* blocks[600][14];`, is it going to be wasted space if I only *occasionally* am using all 14 all of the second dimension or is that space only used when I specifically declare that part of the array?

For example:

```
BITMAP* blocks[600][14];
blocks[0][0] = load_bitmap("brick.bmp", NULL);
blocks[1][0] = load_bitmap("brick2.bmp", NULL);
```

Am I 'wasting' space by not using `blocks[0][1]`, `blocks[0][2]` etc.?

Thanks,

Will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, arrays are contiguous so yes, you are 'wasting' the additional elements if you don't use them.

However, what you are wasting is only a single pointer (8 bytes on a 64-bit machine); not the actual bitmap data. So even if you use only one BITMAP* element in your 600x14 array you're wasting ~67kB; which isn't a massive amount in a modern desktop machine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, exactly what I needed. I will mark as 'accepted answer' in 11 minutes (it won't let me till then).

Comment: Thanks for the extension of your answer, useful as well! Your original answer changed my mind, but then your extension change it again!